# angular directives, typeError undefined is not a function

Tags: angularjs, types, undefined, directive

im having a problem with two directives:

slimScroll:

```
directive("slimScroll", [
    function() {
        return {
            link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
                return ele.slimScroll({
                    height: attrs.scrollHeight || "100%"
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

gives me the following error:

**TypeError: undefined is not a function at link (http://localhost/Sistema/js/directives.js:144:32)**

**The line that references is: 
return ele.slimScroll({**

And this directive:

```
.directive("collapseNav", [
    function() {
        return {
            link: function(scope, ele) {
                var $a, $aRest, $lists, $listsRest, app;
                return $lists = ele.find("ul").parent("li"),
                    $lists.append('<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right icon-has-ul"></i>'),
                    $a = $lists.children("a"),
                    $listsRest = ele.children("li").not($lists),
                    $aRest = $listsRest.children("a"),
                    app = $("#app"),
                    $a.on("click", function(event) {
                        var $parent, $this;
                        return app.hasClass("nav-min") ? !1 : ($this = $(this),
                            $parent = $this.parent("li"),
                            $lists.not($parent).removeClass("open").find("ul").slideUp(),
                            $parent.toggleClass("open").find("ul").stop().slideToggle(), event.preventDefault());
                    }), $aRest.on("click", function() {
                    return $lists.removeClass("open").find("ul").slideUp();
                }), scope.$on("minNav:enabled", function() {
                    return $lists.removeClass("open").find("ul").slideUp();
                });
            }
        };
    }
])
```

gives me this error
**TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at link (http://localhost/Sistema/js/directives.js:93:57)**

**The line that references is:  $listsRest = ele.children("li").not($lists),**

Comment: i have allready load the slimscroll dependency

Answer (score 1):

When you're referencing the second argument of the link function in a directive (in your case `ele`), you are not referencing a full-scale jQuery object reference of the element. Angular bundles with [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), meaning that only some jQuery methods are available.

In your two cases, that means:

1. `slimScroll` is a jQuery plugin that won't get automatically registered with jqLite
2. `.not()` is not available in jqLite

If you want full jQuery support, you'll have to include it in your application and then create a real jQuery object, by doing `jQuery(ele[0])`. The ele[0] references the native DOM element, which is suitable for creating a jQuery element.